# let background div stretch all the way down to the bottom off the page

Tags: css, html, height

Is there a css trick to let a div stretch down to the bottom of the screen without visible
content in it.

Or do I have to resort to javascript?

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try using `min-height:100%;`.

The property is not supported in all browsers, though :( Also, you have to apply this to all parent elements of the div.

Comment: I think I will go with javascript then, it actually looks ok on a laptop but according to someone else the empty space at the bottom looks weird on a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

u can't do that with plain css if u need all browsers support. but u can do some tricks to show that your container is 100% height. for example with background images (according to your website template).

or u can do some javascript coding to make your div 100% height.